# Changing file permissions and ownership on shared drive

Tags: server, permissions, samba

I currently have a Samba server running as a simple backup server. When the server was initially configured the following file ownership and permissions where applied to the shared directories:

```
sudo chmod -R 766 /samba/allusers
sudo chown -R nobody:nogroup /samba/allusers   

sudo setfacl -dm g:nogroup:rw /samba/allusers/
sudo setfacl -dm u:nobody:rw /samba/allusers/
```

The shared directories where intended to act as a sort of "anonymous" share. I now however want to assign ownership to current and new files in the shared directory with the following commands:

```
sudo chmod -R 770 /samba/allusers
sudo chown root:smbrestricted /samba/allusers
```

My question is how this would affect the files currently on the shared directory. My mind is telling me that there could be possible permission errors, but I'm not sure, however here is the ls-command result of the directory at the moment:

```
admin@backupserver:~$ ls -al /samba/allusers
total 60
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45056 Jul  8 21:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 May 29 17:07 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8192 Jul  6 16:26 Server Feb 2013 Backup
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Oct  5  2010 System Volume Information
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Jul  6 17:59 File_1
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Jul  6 16:56 Web Development
```